# How to keep the same content on a website even when navigating pages

Tags: angular

I noticed on ***[Twitter's Website](https://twitter.com/home)*** that it will keep the same Tweets and other information on the page even when you navigate between pages. 
For Example:
I'm on the Twitter home page and see a post about a dog.
I go to the Twitter profile page and a few minutes later go back to the Twitter home page.
I still see the same post and it didn't have to load or anything.

How would I do that in **Angular(Firebase)**?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your goal is to preserve state (data) of your app while you are navigating between different tabs. I think 2 most popular choices in this case with Angular are:

1. **Create a so called store** for your application which will help you preserve state. Something like NGRX would do the job nicely in this case.
2. **Don't use Angular routing but use some kind of tab's component** that only hides html but does not remove your component from DOM itself.

P.S it does not matter what you use for backend. This is purely FE issue.

Comment: its ok to use  `Angular routing`  with some form of `local storage`